# How to use variables from one PHP file in another file's function?

Tags: php

NOTE: I have read about 25 questions thus far that are peripherally related to this, but never answer the question directly of HOW TO USE THOSE VARIABLES CORRECTLY. I apologize if it sounds like a duplicate.

I am rewriting a flat e-commerce site (all hand-made`.htm` files!) so that some of the pages are generated using PHP scripts. This is all just to make my life easier for now. I have told my boss repeatedly that this site needs to be nuked from orbit, and there is a full-blown CMS in the pipeline. In the meantime this site NEEDS to be revamped. Site in question: http://www.leather.com

I have been using a `constructor_page.php` that declares and initializes a few variables such as `$itemName` and `$imagePath` that are used in `include()`'d content pages (trimmed example follows):

```
<?php
$imagePath = 'http://leather.com/images/harley_leather_boots/d81024_ladies_harley_leather_boots_360.jpg';
$itemName = 'Faded Glory Harley Boots';
include 'library/content.php'; //this in turn includes more files like the nav bar
?>
```

This way I just save `constructor_page.php` as the item page in question, modify a few variables, and the `include()` statements take care of the rest. This part works okay.

My issue is with generating "department" pages automatically from the files in the same directory. I would like the index.php to grab those same variables in a loop:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
include $filename;
echo '<div class="related">';
echo '<a href="';
echo $filename; 
echo '">';
echo '<img src="';
echo $imagePath;
echo '" alt="';
echo $imageAlternateText;
echo '" class="frame-related align-left-related"';
echo '></a>';
echo '<a href="';
echo $filename; 
echo '">';
echo $itemName; 
echo '</a>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

This is intended to, for each php file (yes I know it'll recurse to itself), grab the relevant variables and create a nice picture/link inside a  that floats left, in essence generating the department page thumbnails automatically based on whatever php files it finds in there.

Yes, it's horrible. Yes, it's hackish. Needless to say, it does not work due to the scope of the variables. I am open to suggestion here, as all I need is for the department page to generate little pictures and links based on what it finds in the folder SOME HOW. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `global $variable = 'value'` ?

Comment: Forget what people are saying about global statements. Any variable defined in page1.php will be in the global scope automatically, and available to any scripts included by page1.php. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the output and the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 14):

You must have some other problem. Let me demonstrate:

```
<?php // This is index.php
$foo = 'bar';
include('page2.php');
?>


<?php // This is page2.php
include('page3.php');
?>

<?php // This is page3.php
echo $foo;
?>
```

If you go to index.php, it will display "bar". Included PHP scripts inherit the scope where they were included. There's no need to use a "global" statement at any time. If however your page3.php script looked like this:

```
<?php // This is page3.php
function display() {
    echo $foo;
}
display();
?>
```

That wouldn't display anything, because now $foo is in the scope of the display() function, so it would need to be rewritten like this:

```
<?php // This is page3.php
function display() {
    global $foo;
    echo $foo;
}
display();
?>
```

So you must be doing something else wrong if your variables aren't available in other scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Simply declare

```
global $imagePath;
```

(And likewise for other variables you want to use in more than one script or function.)

Comment: I tried this, but in some debug statements ie. `echo $imagePath;` it was still null. Unfortunately this is a managed host so I cannot edit php.ini or anything like that.

Comment: OH and to make this all even more exciting, it's an IIS 6 server.

Answer (score 0):

Like VoteyDIsciple said, you have to declare it at the top of the page first as being a global variable like so:

```
global $imagePath;

$imagePath = 'path/to/the/image.jpg';
```

Then on any page you want to use the global variable you must reference it as being global first before using it.

So on the page you are using echo $imagePath; you must first do this again.

```
global $imagePath;
```

Global variables get pretty dangerous so I would try looking into a more MVC type of framework where your variables you create in your Controllers get passed into your view files. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller

A good MVC Framework I enjoy developing in is Codeigniter http://codeigniter.com

Comment: Yes, I am definitely aware of the issues with global variables, which is why I was trying to avoid them.

I would love to use ANY PHP framework. Unfortunately I'm one-manning this and none of my coworkers know a lick of PHP. Basically I'm trying to write something simple enough for a non-PHP user to modify in order to make content, while still being mostly "PHP magic"

Comment: how about you explain why the answer is wrong. It explains how the variable can be used in each page.