# PHP mysql query x=$variable

Tags: mysql

How i can send $country to second code (**select emr_value from countries where country_name='$country'**) i don't know why $country = "" or null please help

thanks

```
  <?php

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "root";
 $dbname = "db";
global $country;
// Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = "SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_usermeta` where user_id=$user_id and meta_key='custom_field_6' ";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);



 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $country = $row["meta_value"];
    echo $country;


     }
 } else {
     echo "0 results";
 }
$conn->close();

?>
```

Second Code (Here i want to display data for this query (**select emr_value from countries where country_name='$country'**))

```
<?php

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "root";
 $dbname = "db";
global $country;
// Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = "select emr_value from countries where country_name='$country'";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);


     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $emr_value = $row["emr_value"];
    echo "<h1>EMR : " . $emr_value . "</h1>";   
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: include the first file into second one and use the variable. and it's not needed to specify the connections and global variable there. It should work.

Comment: Why have 2 files instead of having 1?

Comment: study [use one php file's variable in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001915/how-to-use-variables-from-one-php-file-in-another-files-function)

Comment: its a one page, how i can solved it, and i see this problem when echo sql = select emr_value from countries where country_name=' Jordan' ,, the problem is a space before variable here - ' Jordan'

Comment: use `...where country_name =trim($country)` It'll take the query as: `... where country_name = 'Jordan'` without the leading or trailing spaces within the variable value. And if it's all in same file then no need of `include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should have only one code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND meta_key='custom_field_6'";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $country = trim($row1["meta_value"]);
        $sql = "SELECT emr_value FROM countries WHERE country_name='$country'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql);

        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<h1>EMR : " . $row2["emr_value"] . "</h1>"; 
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Or create two functions in one code: one that returns $country and one that returns emr_value.